# What symbols are available for easylist?

Tags: symbols, lists, easylist

The [documentation for easylist](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/easylist) indicates that the following symbols are available beyond the default §:

```
\usepackage[pilcrow]{easylist} to use ¶
\usepackage[at]{easylist} to use @
\usepackage[sharp]{easylist} to use #
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist} to use &
```

Are there any other symbols possible to use?

I would like to use ¤.

Answer (score 4):

#### Short answer

No.

#### Longer answer

The package defines `\easylist` in different ways according to the option given at call time and only supports those five symbols.

Heavy surgery would be needed in order to accommodate other symbols.